# Unable to edit the meshes for shape keys

Tags: modeling, animation, shape-keys

I'm unable to edit any meshes when applying a shape key. Any sort of transformation does not show any when I use the value slide. The only thing which transforms is the scale [image: I'm trying to scale the selected part up to the edges of the shape] I've tried to follow tutorials but the mesh never changes for me when I am in edit mode and this only happens when I start using the Shape keys

[image]

Comment: maybe this will help https://vimeo.com/173408647

Comment: Unlike that user when I try to edit my mesh nothing happens the object refuses to change I get red axis lines

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1656" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1656/)                   I'm trying to edit this to construct over time and I seem to be able to get the results if i started with a new shape then keying the constructions. Still unsure why I can't transform that object though

Answer (score 6):

Disable "apply shape key in edit mode"

[image]

Comment: Thanks that helped a great bunch I was also trying to Key frame in a manner similar to After effects instead of treating the shape keys as sliders for separate animations.