# Can't see live changes in edit mode on character

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, object-mode

I've see the opposite of my problem but I can't seem to find anyone who has had this happen. I can see changes only after a bounce back to object mode, but only for some things. In the images below you can see my character has to do the bounce but the cube I throw in to show you this does not.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using shapekeys?

Comment: Yes I am using shape keys.

Comment: I have found several ways to reproduce the problem, but we can only know what wrong in this specific case if you [upload your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: Thank you. When you asked about shape keys I found this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58763/unable-to-edit-the-meshes-for-shape-keys      I forgot to post that it is now fixed. Thank you for your help and sorry for the long response.

Answer (score 1):

The shape keys were pined I found this in my search: [Unable to edit the meshes for shape keys](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58763/unable-to-edit-the-meshes-for-shape-keys)

It now works.